# Why won't this Bootstrap example work?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried numerous times to get Bootstrap to work, however even when I copy an example from Bootstrap's site, it still won't work properly as it does in the example. Here's the code I've uploaded to my server and yes, all the files are in the proper directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script>   <![endif]-->

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work properly"? Have you confirmed with the browser's dev tools that all files are loaded correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Your classes were not correct.
You will have to make sure that since you are using a fixed-top navigation, you will want to put top margin or padding on items directly below them....

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LWpHv/)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse nav navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>



<div class="container">

  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```